# cannot catch a click event on custom android view

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

I have this xml:

```
<com.me.view.button.SwipeableButton
        android:id="@+id/mainMenuSwipeableButton"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        app:button="@drawable/main_menu_button"
        android:visibility="visible" />
```

and:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/icon_menu_press" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_menu" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

why isn't my click caught when i have this code?

```
 setCloseToolTipClickListener(getMainLayout().findViewById(R.id.mainMenuSwipeableButton),  tooltipView);

  private void setCloseToolTipClickListener(View view, final LinearLayout tooltip) {
    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        tooltip.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: You getting any error or logs?

Comment: nothing, just never reach breakpoint on `tooltip.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Comment: Does it change anything if you set `android:clickable="true"` in the control's properties?